# jQuery menu styling

Tags: jquery, css

I've seen a really nice jQuery-like menu on force.com (after you log-in). And I can't find a tutorial/example on how to create it using jQuery.

It looks like this:

Before hover:

[image]

On Hover:

[image]

On Click:

[image]

Anyone knows where I can find a good example on how to create one of these?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic one :) however u do need css to style it how ever u wish :)

```
<ul>
    <li class="header">Header</li>
    <li class="menu" style="display:none;">
       <ul>
          <li>Me</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>



$('.header').click(function (){
 $('.menu').toggle();
});
```